# C Conversion Specifiers

Tags: c, printf

I'm relatively new to programming and am currently learning C in school. I was studying and came across a question and was having difficulty finding the answer online, so I decided to ask my own question.

What does the integer behind the % in a conversion specifier mean?

For example, I've noticed that %s is sometimes written as %5s or %-8s.

I know it has to do with spacing and have also experimented a bit on my own, but I seem to be having some trouble to precisely pinpoint the functionality of the integers.

Any other words of advice or tips are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I've done some research and experimenting, and learned that the numbers have to do with spaces. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%4d\n", 1);
    printf("%8d\n", 2);
}
```

would output:

```
    1
        2
```

If you include negative integers behind the conversion specifier, then it means that the `printf` will format the output to have spaces *behind* the output. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%-4d%d", 1, 2);
}
```

will output

```
1    2
```

I hope this helps anybody new to formatting output and gets confused.

Comment: Check the help of [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and see if you can figure it out yourself. Check the format specifier sub specifiers descriptions.

Comment: Refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: __R.T.F.M.__ (_`.`s added for pause effect_) :)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: a -1, no research effort, at all. neither a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

4 Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %. After the %, the following appear in sequence:

...

> — An optional minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer
>   characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces (by default)
>   on the left (or right, if the left adjustment flag, described later,
>   has been given) to the field width. The field width takes the form of
>   an asterisk * (described later) or a nonnegative decimal integer

and further

> 5 As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be
>   indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an int argument supplies the
>   field width or precision. The arguments specifying field width, or
>   precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the argument
>   (if any) to be converted. **A negative field width argument is taken
>   as a - flag followed by a positive field width**. A negative precision
>   argument is taken as if the precision were omitted.

And at last

> 6 The flag characters and their meanings are:
>
> - The result of the conversion is left-justified within the field. (It is 
>     right-justified if this flag is not specified.)